# What's the proper use of output property in Octave?

Tags: octave

I am not sure what is the use of output while using `fminunc`.

```
>>options = optimset('GradObj','on','MaxIter','1');
>>initialTheta=zeros(2,1);
>>[optTheta, functionVal, exitFlag, output, grad, hessian]= 
fminunc(@CostFunc,initialTheta,options);

>> output
output =
scalar structure containing the fields:
    iterations = 11
    successful = 10
    funcCount = 21
```

Even when I use max no of `iteration = 1` still it is giving no of `iteration = 11`??

Could anyone please explain me why is this happening?
help me with `grad` and `hessian` properties too, means the use of those.

Answer (score 1):

Given we don't have the full code, I think the easiest thing for you to do to understand exactly what is happening is to just set a breakpoint in `fminunc.m` itself, and follow the logic of the code. This is one of the nice things about working with Octave, since the source code is provided and you can check it freely (there's often useful information in octave source code in fact, such as references to papers which they relied on for the implementation, etc).

From a quick look, it doesn't seem like `fminunc` expects a `maxiter` of 1. Have a look at line 211:

```
211   while (niter < maxiter && nfev < maxfev && ! info)
```

Since `niter` is initialised just before (at line `176`) with the value of `1`, in theory this loop will never be entered if your `maxiter` is 1, which defeats the whole point of the optimization.

There are other interesting things happening in there too, e.g. the inner while loop starting at line 272:

```
272     while (! suc && niter <= maxiter && nfev < maxfev && ! info)
```

This uses "shortcut evaluation", to first check if the previous iteration was "unsuccessful", before checking if the number of iterations are less than "maxiter".

In other words, if the previous iteration was successful, you don't get to run the inner loop at all, and you never get to increment `niter`.

What flags an iteration as "successful" seems to be defined by the ratio of "actual vs predicted reduction", as per the following (non-consecutive) lines:

```
286         actred = (fval - fval1) / (abs (fval1) + abs (fval));
...
295         prered = -t/(abs (fval) + abs (fval + t));
296         ratio = actred / prered;
...
321       if (ratio >= 1e-4)
322         ## Successful iteration.
...
326         nsuciter += 1;
...
328       endif
329
330       niter += 1;
```

In other words, it seems like fminunc will respect your maxiters ignoring whether these have been "successful" or "unsuccessful", with the exception that it does not like to "end" the algorithm at a "successful" turn (since the success condition needs to be fulfilled first before the maxiters condition is checked).

Obviously this is an academic point, since you shouldn't even be entering this inner loop when you couldn't even make it past the outer loop in the first place.

I cannot really know exactly what is going on without knowing your specific code, but you should be able to follow easily if you run your code with a breakpoint at fminunc. The maths behind that implementation may be complex, but the code itself seems fairly simple and straightforward enough to follow.

Good luck!

Comment: Also, it goes without saying, if you figure out what's going on and you feel this represents a bug, feel free to contribute to the project by submitting a bug report at the octave tracker! :)

Comment: Hi @MdArif, I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking me how to debug octave code?

Comment: Okay @Tasos Papastylianou  I think I was trying to make a joke on which no one was supposed to laugh.